# Is there any way to send an automated email alert before due date

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a field call due date in a custom object. Is there any possibility to send an email alert before three days automatically without touching the record please suggest

Answer (score 6):

You should use [time-based workflows](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=workflow_time_action_considerations.htm&language=en_US) on due_date field and specify the days in time then in the action you can select emails alerts.